# How to cluster a group of near points to single point?

Tags: c++

I'm using ORB in openCV3 C++ to detect some features in image and get back the real coordinates. But I'm having some points that are very very near to each other which I don't need I just need one of them.

```
X=[0.493953,0.490301,0.540664,0.575473,0.423641,0.49213,0.366055,0.395635,0.488464,0.486621,0.49213,0.358992,0.397844,0.575473,0.397844,0.425734,0.576992,0.580014,0.425734,-0.810798];
Y=[0.141909,0.154724,-0.03982,0.260174,-0.0699365,0.140797,0.121944,0.31197,0.13856,0.153795,0.137043,0.0239328,0.310085,0.256748,0.312835,-0.0683147,0.255281,0.253498,-0.0629622,-0.932006];
```

I need to group the near points from the x and their corresponding in Y in a new array so that it will be:

```
X_new=[-0.810798, 0.358992, 0.395635, 0.423641, 0.486621, 0.540664, 0.576992]
y_new=[-0.932006,0.0239328, 0.31197, -0.0699365, 0.153795, -0.03982, 0.255281]
```

I tried first to sort the data from x and run nested loops and if condition based on the distance between the x coordinates, but I didn't get the output as needed.

Comment: Why don't you use the Euclidean distance as it will give better information about the proximity between two points.

Comment: Or may be use [kmeans clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) with k=6, where k is the number of clusters.

Comment: I can't use the kmeans as k is not always will be 6 it is changing depend on the output of the feature detection

Comment: Then, maybe try to figure out a threshold distance and if the distance between two points is less than that, merge them and instead add a new point at their place which can be the mean of these two points. You can find this threshold by doing some experiments on a set of images. or maybe randomly choose one.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't get the output as needed."? What is the difference between what you want and what you need? By that I don't mean the numbers but qualitatively, what do the numbers represent?

Comment: Why exactly these points? And where is `0,366055`,`0,121944`?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, a nicer idea will be to use [k means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). Although, you may not get the exact same points as you mentioned in your question, yet those will be a good approximation of what you desire to achieve. Hope it helps.